# Merging every nth files in a folder and delete used one

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

I have folder with 30000 txt files, each file is 50-60kb. I need to merge them into 2.5mb txt files.And remove the one that was merging. My code would need to be something like: `for f in *,50; do cat file1,file2...file49 > somefile.txt;done` Of course this is pseudocode. I would need to merge files in package of 50 files, then remove the used one. Can someone please help me?

Comment: 1. Deleting and re-posting the same question doesn't help you.    2. Merge all the files into one file and then split that with `split -c 2500000`.   3.  You say "My code would need to be something like" but it really **doesn't**, you only **think** it needs to be like that.  That was a bad solution for your last question and a terrible solution for this almost identical one.    Your "need" is an example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: i had to delete question, that what stackexchange told me to do. It has connected with my other question and said it was duplicated, but it wasn't. But making ```split -c 2500000``` would make me txt files with missing characteres or incomplete sentences...now i have 30 000 txt files as a whole so for me it would be better to add 1..49,50..99.100..149....etc than making big file and then splitting.

Comment: SE didn't tell you to delete your question, you chose to do that because you wanted to repost it.  And SE didn't tell you it 're supposed to learn from answers you get here, not just repost the same qwas a duplicate (I did, because it was pretty nearly identical but with `$((i+1)) .. $((i+49))`  instead of just to  `$((i+4))`).   Instead of something so hideously ugly and prone to user-error & typos, use `printf` as I showed you in a comment to your last question.   You're supposed to learn from answers you get here, not just repost the same question with trivial variations.

Comment: i have seen many many answears before posting quest. something like that  i getting me every 50th file ```for file in `find folder -type f | awk 'NR %50 == 0'`; do echo $file;done
``` but how do i now add from $file all files till next $file?

Comment: If you can't just merge them all into one big file and then split that, then iterate over every filename and append them to an output filename.  When that output file is over 2.5MB, change the output filename.   Repeat until you run out of input filenames.   You do not need to and should not explicitly list file1,file2,file3,...,file49.

Comment: how do i do it @cas

Comment: You do it by paying attention to your own criteria, and not distracting yourself with irrelevancies.  Your criteria is "merge into files approx 2.5MB each in size".  Your fixation with concatenating 50 files at a time is the irrelevant distraction.   See my previous comment for the algorithm.

Comment: maybe someone, have some code or examples?

Comment: @cas come on, no need to be so brusque. You don't know if the "2.5M" or the "50 files" is the more relevant criterion. You just seem to have assumed that the OP wants 2.5M for some reason. Maybe what the OP really cares about is that each concatenated file contains the contents of exactly 50 originals and it's the size that is an irrelevancy so it is you, not the OP, who is distracting yourself. K.Mazur, please [edit] your question and clarify what you want. Do you want exactly 2.5M of data per file or do you want exactly 50 files per merged file? Or maybe you need *no more* than 2.5 per file?

Comment: @terdon I do know.  that was the focus of his deleted-and-reposted-it question.  Otherwise it was an exact duplicate of his previous question (with the trivial difference of 5 files rather than 50), rather than an almost-imperceptibly different almost-dupe.   If I'm "brusque", it's because he posted a dupe (with the same awful code fragment) of his prev question, deleted the dupe, then reposted it.  and compounded the annoyance by failing to learn anything from the answers to his previous question.

Comment: @cas all of the OP's questions, including the deleted one, seem more focused on the number of files than on the size. I don't know what makes you think the size is the important criterion.

Comment: @terdon yes. XY problem.  and if, by some chance you're right and it is about the number of files and not the 2.5MB size, then it's a dupe of his previous question. same question, different number of files.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
files=( ./input-file*(Nn.) )
typeset -Z3 n=1
while
 (( $#files > 0 )) &&
   cat $files[1,50] > merged-file$n.txt &&
   rm -f $files[1,50]
do
  files[1,50]=()
  ((n++))
done
```

There `./input-file*(Nn.)` expands to the files that match `./input-file*`, but with 3 glob qualifiers further classifying that:

- `N`: nullglob: makes the glob expand to nothing instead of aborting with an error when there's no match. That one you often want when setting an array from a glob and it's fine for that array to be empty in the end:
- `n`: `numericglobsort`: change the sorting from a default of lexical to numerical (in effect combination of both), so that `input-file2` sorts before `input-file10` for instance.
- `.`: restrict to *regular* files (ignore directories, symlinks, fifos...)

`typeset -Z3 n` makes `$n` a variable zero-padded to width 3, so we get `merged-file001.txt`, ... `merged-file049.txt`...

Then we loop as long as there are elements in the `$files` array and there's no error, concatenating batches of 50 at a time (and whatever's left for the last batch).

The same with bash 4.4+ and GNU tools:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'input-file*' -type f -print0 |
    sort -zV
)
n=0
set -- "${files[@]}"
while
 (( $# > 0 )) &&
   printf -v padded_n %03d "$n" &&
   cat "${@:0:50}" > "merged-file$padded_n.txt" &&
   rm -f "${@:0:50}"
do
  shift "$(( $# >= 50 ? 50 : $# ))"
  ((n++))
done
```

Where `find` does the job of zsh's `./input-file*(N.)`, `sort -V` does the numeric (version) sort, and we use positional parameters and `shift` in the loop as `bash` arrays are quite limited.

Comment: Why would you use `rm -f`? That seems to just be adding a (small) risk for no benefit. If something is write protected, maybe it shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: @terdon, `rm` without `-f` is for interactive use, you generally don't want it in scripts. Here the specification is clear that files that have been merged must be deleted.

Comment: If the cat fails mid-way and some files were added to the archive, no file will be erased.

Comment: @ImHere, yes, and `n` and `$files` will be left as is, so you can investigate and fix the problem and restart from there in that case. I figured that was probably the best approach.

Comment: Why do you need to set the locale to `C` for find. Does it fail to report all files?

Comment: @ImHere, yes, that to be a closer equivalent to zsh's one. With GNU `find`, `-name 'foo*'` only matches on files whose name starts with `foo` and what follows is valid text in the locale. With `zsh`, what follows doesn't have to be valid text in the locale. `LC_ALL=C` guarantees any sequence of bytes will be valid text.

Comment: But the match of the `'*'` is made by find, not the shell. Why is the shell name important?

Comment: @ImHere, it's not particularly important, it's just that I use `LC_ALL=C` with GNU `find` because earlier I said *The same (implied: as the zsh code above) with bash 4.4+ and GNU tools*. bash's `foo*` also matches on `foo` followed by anything, but for different reasons (the pattern is interpreted byte-wise instead of character-wise if matched against a string that cannot be decoded (which works here, but can have very surprising consequences for other patterns, though that's beside the point here).

Comment: Well, `find -name file-*` wont match a file named `file-$'\Ud847'` as a surrogate point is an invalid character in a utf-8 locale (the one I am using). But yes, bash (and zsh) will match such file on globbing. So, my point, it is find the one to blame for this issue (if that is a mistake). @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @ImHere, yes, it's a problem with `find` (and possibly with the POSIX specification which may be requiring that behaviour, or at least that `?` or `[^x]` cannot match a byte that doesn't form part of a valid character, I'm not sure the POSIX position is as clear for `*`).

Comment: to work around the lack of `shift` for a named array, I think you could do `for (( i=0; i < "${#a[@]}"; i += k))` and then use `"${a[@]:i:k}"` to get the list of files to process each round.

Answer (score 0):

This script is:

1. For bash (as tagged),
2. Avoiding find (which fails on invalid characters),
3. Making sure that only plain files are processed (no dirs),
4. Using `sort` to sort numerically (well, by version) and
5. Joining on `k` files (variable count)
6. Removing **one** file at a time (avoid copying a block of files that wont get erased)

```bsh
dir="myDir"

readarray -td $'\0' files < <(
   for f in ./"$dir"/in-file*; do
       if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then printf '%s\0' "$f"; fi
   done |
       sort -zV
)

k=50
rm -f ./"$dir"/joined-files*.txt
for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
   n=$((i/k+1))
   cat "${files[i]}"  >> ./"$dir"/joined-files$n.txt &&
       rm -f "${files[i]}"
done
```